# Curves on reducible CM-abelian surfaces.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, complex-multiplication

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve with complex multiplication. Consider an abelian surface $A = E \times E$. What can be said about curves on $A$?

I guess they must be rather specific. I'm not even sure if there could be curves of big genus. I would also be interesting on any literature on such surfaces.

Comment: Any smooth projective variety contains smooth curves of arbitrarily high genus.

Comment: One can use the theory in Chapter 4 of Mumford's book _Abelian Varieties_ to describe the Neron--Severi group and the cone of effective curves on $A$ fairly explicitly. I can try to give more details if you are interested.

Comment: @bertram how to proof your claim?